# silverlight in html EMAIL body

Tags: silverlight, email, html-email

I have a news letter which i did in silverlight, is there a way to send it in email. like as you include html tags, is there a way to include silverlight xap package in it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably better to reference a webpage containing your silverlight content.

Technically, you could put the path to the .xap hosted on a website into an HTML email body, but nearly all mail clients will not display this - most even prevent images from loading by default.

Answer (score 2):

Most email systems will prevent you from embedding active content like SilverLight, as it presents a security risk. Your only option probably is to put your SilverLight app on the web, and just email a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't if you want your newsletter to be read by anyone. See [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners/) for a good list of do's and don'ts when sending emails.

Answer (score -3):

***Don't listen to those guys, they're probably FlashHeads... ;)***

Besides that they give up too easily. More power to ya!

I assume this newsletter is for an audence that specifically desires your content: i.e a club or similar organization that doesn't have a windows based webserver.

What you do is attach the file in such a way that they drag a zip containing the files that would normally be served from a website to the hard drive - right click - extract all then they run it by clicking on an **HTML** file with .htm extension that hosts the silverlight plugin instead of an aspx file.

One note that probably won't matter to you is that without a server backing this up the content can't really send you back any info but it CAN get dynamic info that comes from say RSS feeds or WCF services hosted on the web.